# Read 1st Column of Excel Workbook Into Array

Tags: c#, epplus-4

Use `OpenFileDialog`with EPPlus.  I get a compile error of:

```
The name 'sheet' does not exist in the current context
```

Now, the obvious issue is how do I associate the selected Excel file with my EPPPlus & 2 what do I do to remove the error above?

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;

private void btn_ReadExcelToArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  fd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx";
  fd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
  if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {          
    var columnimport = sheet.Cells["A2:A"];
    foreach (var cell in columnimport)
    {
        var column1CellValue = cell.GetValue<string>();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes there is - but perhaps you will show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c

Comment: Do you need to support both `.xls` and `.xlsx` files?

Comment: @DStanley only .xlsx files.

Comment: Why don't you just read it straight into an array rather than a datatable?  Or at worst fill a `List<>` and convert that to an array.

Comment: @DStanley my beginning skills aren't sure how to read that into a List<string> or an Array.  I am unclear of the set-up.  I know how to take the datatable to an array, but not go straight to an array.

Comment: You don't need a `DataTable`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221916/microsoft-office-interop-excel-or-epplus-for-read-a-huge-or-not-excel-file) on reading a column of data using EPPlus.