# Does EPPlus requires Excel to be installed on the sever

Tags: .net, spreadsheet, epplus

I am no table to find the answer on the new do posting here
Does EPPlus requires Excel to be installed on the sever?

If yes what are the possible good alternative for .NET that doesn't require excel to be installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116283/is-it-required-to-install-ms-excel-or-office-on-server-to-read-an-excel-file-in No it is a standalone library that doesn't require MS-Office to be installed. See their requirements also.

Comment: @steve i came across that answer. So it doesnt require it even on reading the excel?

Comment: No it does not. It can read or write files without installing Excel on the server.

Comment: This link has the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221916/microsoft-office-interop-excel-or-epplus-for-read-a-huge-or-not-excel-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221916/microsoft-office-interop-excel-or-epplus-for-read-a-huge-or-not-excel-file)